# How does one define helper functions inside def block in Scala?

Tags: scala

I would like to create a `helper function` inside of a function, then call the `helper function` and return it for the original call of the function definition.

For example:

```
def g(arg1: List[T]): List[T] = {
    def h(arg1: List[T], arg2: [T]): List[T] = {
        //code to call here
    }
    //call h with an initial value
    h(arg, 12345)
}
...
...
//in main()
g(List(1,2,3)) // --> returns result of h(List(1,2,3), 12345)
```

I would like to define the function inside the original function's scope, since it is not pertinent to the other functions in the code.

What is the `Scala` way of doing this?

Is there also a completely different way to create this same functionality? If so, how?

(I thought of this due to the `let` + `in` paradigm used in `OCaml`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scala way to do it is :

```
def g(arg1: List[T]): List[T] = {

   def h(arg2: T): List[T] = {

    // arg1 is already available here. (closure)
    //code to call here
  }

  //call h with an initial value
  h(12345)
}
```

Another way is

```
val h = new Function1[T, List[T]] {

    def apply(arg2: T): List[T] = {
         // function, arg1 is still available.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this also helped me understand closures in another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can define local functions inside other functions more or less as you have written. E.g.

```
object LocalFunctionTest {
  def g(arg: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    def h(lst: List[Int], i: Int) = {
      val l = lst.map(_ + i)
      l :+ 3
    }
    h(arg, 12345)
  }
}

scala> LocalFunctionTest.g(List(1,2,3))
res1: List[Int] = List(12346, 12347, 12348, 3)
```